# Swift 5 unable to add action to custom button(addTarget issues in AVPlayerViewController)

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried all the tutorials but I keep failing to add action to a button added programatically.

I've tried adding the functions to viewdidload and viewdidappear but it doesn't work.

```
class videoPlayer: AVPlayerViewController {
// PROPERTIES
let button = UIButton()
.
.
.
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("video controller here!")

        //Play the Video
        let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "v1", ofType: "mp4")!
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: url))
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
            playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = false
        }


        //ADDING CUSTOM UI
        button.setTitle("TEST", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.sizeToFit()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonAction(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)
        playerViewController.contentOverlayView?.addSubview(button)

    }

    // MARK :- Functions
    @objc func buttonAction(sender :UIButton) {
        print("Button tapped")
    }
.
.
.
}
```

A red button does appear on the top left corner but on clicking nothing happens.

Comment: Not sure you're using the correct init method for UIButton - check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624028-init

Comment: Set `button.superView!.clipToBounds = true` and see if it is still visible. button will not be clickable its outside the `superView`. Also check if button or button's superview user interaction is enabled.

Comment: @TheTiger superView is found nil when controller loads...

Comment: Then there is no issue with button ... Issue is where you adding this button. Well every view controller's outlets generate after viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @TheTiger any suggestions?

Comment: Trying adding your button in presenting block after some delay where the play()  function is written.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a frame like

```
button.frame = CGRect(x:20,y:20,width:50,height:50)
```

Comment: Adding the frame only changes the button location and shape. It still won't click... (no "button tapped" message)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
While copying some code over I didnt realise I was creating a new avplayercontroller.
instead setting self.player = player worked!

Basically The buttons were displaying but their bounding rect was under the newly created avplayercontroller().
It was so stupid of me to create a avplayercontroller in a avplayercontrolview.

```
let videoURL = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "v1", ofType: "mp4")!
let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: videoURL))
self.player = player
self.showsPlaybackControls = false
self.player?.play()
```